# OnBindViewHolder no suitable method found to override using with await to method

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In class ContactsAdapter I have method OnBindViewHolder, inside of that I call await DirectToLoadImageAsync(stringURL, my_contacts_view.vImage). await method makes the OnBindViewHolder be formed to that:

```
public class ContactsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter, View.IOnClickListener
    {

    public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnBindViewHolderAsync(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
    ...
    await DirectToLoadImageAsync(stringURL, my_contacts_view.vImage);
    ...
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task DirectToLoadImageAsync(string stringURL, CircleImageView vImage)
            {
                var resultImg = await LoadImageAsync(stringURL);
                vImage.SetImageBitmap(resultImg);

            }

    private System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Bitmap> LoadImageAsync(string stringURL)
            {
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadImage(stringURL)); 
            }

    private Bitmap LoadImage(string stringURL)
            {
             ...
            }
    }
```

how to make not to get error: OnBindViewHolder no suitable method found to override using with await to method ?

Answer (score 0):

> OnBindViewHolder no suitable method found to override using with await to method ?

Can’t use await keyword in this method as you can’t use `async` keyword in method signature due to incompatible return type, and please note that your `OnBindViewHolder` has renamed to `OnBindViewHolderAsync`.

An `async` method has to return either `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>`, and returning `void` should only be used when making an event handler async.  In the case of the `OnBindViewHolder` method noted above, its return type is void, which can’t be changed to return `Task` as the OS method that calls it obviously does not use the `await` keyword and so can’t handle a `Task`being returned. Thus you can’t add the `async` keyword to the above method and therefore can’t use the `await` keyword when calling an `async` method from the above method.

#### Solution :

Modify your code like this :

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder (RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    ...
    Task.Run(async () => {
        try
        {
            await DirectToLoadImageAsync(stringURL, my_contacts_view.vImage);
        }
        // Catch any other exceptinons that may have occured
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea but then what, you still need to update the UI which would require `RunOnUIThread` which is not available there?